# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lets-encrypt, multisite

My configuration is very simple:

I handle calls to two different apps whose index.php file is placed in:

```
/var/www/html/mars/public/index.php
```

and

```
/var/www/html/neptune/public/index.php
```

The two apps are invoked via `https://mars.ddns.net` and `https://neptune.ddns.net`.

In the /var/www/html folder I created an .htaccess file to manage the two calls:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>.
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "mars\.ddns\.net"
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mars/public/index.php?/$1 [L].

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "neptune\.ddns\.net"
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ neptune/public/index.php?/$1 [L].
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have not configured any virtualhost and in the Apache configuration

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

and

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf** (I installed Let's Encrypt)

I have only inserted the following code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">.
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Everything works fine and the calls are directed to the right app thus eliminating "/appfolder/public/index.php" from the url.
The htaccess file instead can't handle calls to already existing files.
The code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

seems not to be executed.
I also tried with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

and with:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But the calls always point to the var/www/html/appfolder/public/index.php file instead of the existing file

Comment: "calls to already existing files" - What is the full path to these files? _Aside:_ you have erroneous dots/periods at the end of several of your lines - these should be removed.

Comment: sorry to have asked a non-existent question: the posted code works fine. Rather, the calls I made to the app were wrong. I was able to notice (once again) thanks to @MrWhite's comment.